# object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-templates

I can't find any solution to my issue with similar kind of error.

The error is when I try to edit object:

> 'Intention' object has no attribute 'get'

I have it in line with form.as_p:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="{{ form_url }}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

controller code:

```
def edit(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = IntentionForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            intention = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('intention-show', args=[intention.id])) # Redirect after POST
    else:
        intention = Intention.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = IntentionForm(intention) # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('intentions/templates/form.html', 
                                {'form': form, 'form_url': reverse_lazy('intention-edit', args=[intention.id])},
                                 context_instance=RequestContext(request)  
                             )
```

Could someone give me any advice?

Trackback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/intentions/3/edit

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'intentions',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/marek/devel/django/prayer/intentions/templates/form.html, error at line 4
   'Intention' object has no attribute 'get'
   1 : {% extends "layout.html" %}


   2 : {% block content %}


   3 :  <form action="{{ form_url }}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}


   4 :   {{ form.as_p }} 


   5 :  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />


   6 :  </form>


   7 : {% endblock %}


   8 : 

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/marek/devel/django/prayer/intentions/views.py" in edit
  55.                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request)  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  176.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render
  84.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  571.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  721.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  772.                             current = current()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in as_p
  238.             errors_on_separate_row = True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _html_output
  143.         top_errors = self.non_field_errors() # Errors that should be displayed above all fields.
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in non_field_errors
  246.         return self.errors.get(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, self.error_class())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  115.             self.full_clean()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  270.         self._clean_fields()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
  281.             value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in value_from_datadict
  205.         return data.get(name, None)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /intentions/3/edit
Exception Value: 'Intention' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Yes. Post the full traceback.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
intention = Intention.objects.get(pk=id)
form = IntentionForm(intention) # An unbound form
```

The first argument to a form is the data but you are passing the instance. To properly pass the instance you should use:

```
intention = Intention.objects.get(pk=id)
form = IntentionForm(instance=intention) # An unbound form
```

Comment: how could i have missed that, i read the documentation 10 times https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: one of the rare times my problem has been succinctly answered without requiring an extra hour of contextual investigation and experimentation. thank you!

Answer (score 33):

The above answer is correct, however, this error can also be generated by incorrectly passing arguments in the **init** of a form, which is used for an admin model.

Example:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Notice the double passing of self?  It should be:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Live long you man. Thanks. I had similar typo with host argument.

Comment: I just searched for hours to find this answer which hinted at me having a similar issue. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Found this typo in one blog, but sir you saved me :) +1

Answer (score 8):

In Django, be careful how you name your views and models.

In my case, I had this in `models.py`:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    ...
```

In `views.py`, I had:

```
def contact(request):
    ...
```

Then, in `urls.py`, I had:

```
from .views import Contact
```

So, I was actually importing the model class, and not the contact function, so my error was:

```
'Contact' object has no attribute 'get'
```

That object has no attribute `get`. That's suppose to come from `views.py`, not a `model`.

Comment: Unbelievable, Exactly what I had in my situation! Valuable answer.